# How to (de)serialise JSON data in Silverlight using a different name to member variable

Tags: .net, silverlight, json, serialization, silverlight-2.0

I have the following members defined in a class that I'm trying to deserialise:

```
[DataMemberAttribute(Name = "cust_title")]
        public String Title { get; set; }
        [DataMemberAttribute(Name = "cust_description")]
        public String Description { get; set; }
```

For some reason, the deserialisation fails (it seems to ignore the DataMemberAttribute).

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the answer out by a bit of trial and error. In order to use the `[DataMemberAttribute]` you must also put `[DataContractAttribute]` above your class definition:

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public class MyClass
{
  [DataMemberAttribute(Name="test_test")]
  public String Test { get; set; }
}
```